# Trying to join worker node to master master status ready worker status not ready

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I am following all the steps from this link : https://github.com/justmeandopensource/kubernetes

after running the join command in the worker node it's getting added to master, but the status of the worker node is getting changed to ready.

From the logs I got the following :

```
Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false 
reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:dock
Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
kubelet.go:2266 -- node "XXXXXXXXX" not found. (xxxxx is the masters 
host/node name)
```

To establish CNI I am using flannel and also tried with weave and many other 
  CNI networks but the results are the same

points to ponder:

--->  worker node kubelet status is healthy
---> trying to run kubeadm init command in the worker node,its showing the status of kubelet might be unhealthy. (Not able to make worker node master by running the kubeadm init command but kubeadm join command is working.After joining kubectl get nodes is showing the worker node but status is notready)

Thank you for the help

Comment: you can try reinstalling `kubernetes-cni` i think your weave is not healthy because it cannot create a network because your dir /opt/cni/bin/ is empty in worker node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I followed exactly the instructions on github`s site you shared, and did not face similar error.

The only extra steps I needed to do, to suppress errors, detected by pre-flight checks of kubeadm init:

> [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-ipv4-ip_forward]: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contents are not set to 1
>   [preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with --ignore-preflight-errors=...

was to set appropriate flag by running:

```
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

State of my cluster nodes:

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
centos-master   Ready    master   18h   v1.13.1
centos-worker   Ready    <none>   18h   v1.13.1
```

I verified cluster condition by deploying&exposing sample application and everything seems to be working fine:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=gcr.io/hello-minikube-zero-install/hello-node
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --port=8080
```

I`m getting valid response from hello-world node.js app:

```
 curl 10.100.113.255:8080
 Hello World!#
```

What IP address you have put to your /etc/hosts files ?

Comment: Are you able to run centos-worker as master by running kubeadm init if so can u send me the logs

Comment: I guess you meant logs from kubeadm init run inside coentos-master node, init phases are meant for master node, not for worker.

Comment: can u try making your worker node as master and check joining your master node as worker and can u tell me if its working